# Remotely retrieve a file from hdfs and store it locally in a node

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I want to write a job in which each mapper checks if a file from hdfs is stored in the node that is being executed.If this doesn't happen I want to retrieve it from hdfs and store it locally in this node.Is this possible?

EDIT: I am trying to do this (3) Preprocessing for Repartition Join, as described here: [link](http://mapreducejoin.weebly.com/join-algorithm-in-mapreduce.html)

Comment: By stored locally, do you mean in the data node, or at a pre-defined location on the node running the mapper instance? Can you expand on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @Chris Thanks!I guess it's the second.I 've added what exactlty I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DistributedCache](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache) feature in Hadoop can be used to distribute the side data or auxiliary data required for the completion of the job. Here ([1](http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module5.html#auxdata), [2](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r0.20.2/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache)) are some interesting articles for the same.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's what I 've thought too but I was not sure because the pseudocode in the problem I try to solve is a little bit confusing..

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to do this? The **Data Locality** principle used by Hadoop does this for you. Well, it does not move the data, it does move the program.

This comes from the Wikipedia page about Hadoop:

> The jobtracker schedules map/reduce jobs to tasktrackers with an
>   awareness of the data location. An example of this would be if node A
>   contained data (x,y,z) and node B contained data (a,b,c). The
>   jobtracker will schedule node B to perform map/reduce tasks on (a,b,c)
>   and node A would be scheduled to perform map/reduce tasks on (x,y,z)

And the reason the computation is moved to the data and not the other way around is explained in the Hadoop documentation itself:

> “Moving Computation is Cheaper than Moving Data” A computation requested by an application is much more efficient if it is executed
>   near the data it operates on. This is especially true when the size of
>   the data set is huge. This minimizes network congestion and increases
>   the overall throughput of the system. The assumption is that it is
>   often better to migrate the computation closer to where the data is
>   located rather than moving the data to where the application is
>   running. HDFS provides interfaces for applications to move themselves
>   closer to where the data is located.